# Numpy array assignment inside class

Tags: python, class, numpy, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.2.3 with NumPy 1.6.1.
I would be very grateful if someone could explain me what does NumPy do when I try to access (in two different ways) an element of a NumPy array.

**Code**:

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self,q):
        self.coord = q
        self.firstel = q[0]
        self.secondel = q[1:2]

q = np.array([10,20])   # numpy array
my_object = MyClass(q)  # object of MyClass

print('original','q:',q,' / coord:',my_object.coord,' / 2elements:',my_object.firstel,my_object.secondel])

q[0],q[1] = 30,40 # modification of the  elements of q

print('modified','q:',q,' / coord:',my_object.coord,' / elements:', my_object.firstel, my_object.secondel])
```

`q` is a numpy array that I pass as an argument to `MyClass`. I store it in a variable called `coord` inside the class. Then I access the first and the second element of `q` in two different ways inside the class.

When I run the code above, I get this:

```
original q: [10 20]  / coord: [10 20]  / elements: [10, array([20])]
modified q: [30 40]  / coord: [30 40]  / elements: [10, array([40])]
```

The variable `firstel` **is not updated** when `q` is changed but the variable `secondel` **is**.

What happened with `q[0]` and `q[1:2]` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `firstel` variable is a (immutable) *value* and thus never updated:

```
self.firstel = q[0]  # and stays this value once and for all
```

whilst the `secontel` variable is a *view* on the original array and so will be updated:

```
self.secondel = q[1:2]
```

.

One way to solve this would be to make `firstel` a method:

```
def firstel(self):
    return self.q[0]
```

This probably makes it clearer what the *intent* of firstel and `secondel` is in your class.

Comment: Thanks ! It is clear. I was expecting something like this. Just a comment: there was no actual "problem" in my question but rather 2 different behaviours that I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Andy's explanation is spot on. As to how to overcome that limitation, I don't like having to type empty parentheses all over the place, so for this kind of class attributes I prefer to go with [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), probably influenced by numpy's `shape`, `dtype` and the like:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, q):
        self.coord = np.asarray(q)

    @property
    def firstel(self):
        """The first element of self.coord"""
        return self.coord[0]

    @property
    def secondel(self):
        """The second element of self.coord"""
        return self.coord[1]
```

And now:

```
>>> q = np.array([10, 20])
>>> my_object = MyClass(q)
>>> my_object.firstel
10
>>> my_object.secondel
20
>>> q[:] = [30, 40]
>>> my_object.firstel
30
>>> my_object.secondel
40
```